# When should answers be converted to comments?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answer-quality

Recently an answer I posted to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11958/what-is-this-anomaly-that-supermans-spacecraft-passes-on-his-way-to-earth) was converted to a comment by a moderator, apparently because it was considered a non-serious answer.  I posted it as an answer rather than a comment because I found the image match and the reasoning behind the answer compelling, even though the answer was not in-universe for Superman.  I am frustrated by the change to a comment because it misrepresents my intent; I was not making a joke, I was trying to logically answer a question that probably has no in-universe answer.  I knew the answer wasn't conventional and that I'd take my lumps in downvotes from some members, but I was surprised by an outright deletion.

Should I give up on posting unconventional answers on scifi?

When should moderators convert answers to comments and when should they let the upvotes/downvotes run their course?

Edit: The converted answer was

> Clearly, it is the Nexus energy ribbon from Star Trek: Generations. Since the Nexus is timeless and connects all possible realities, there's no reason for it not to be cruising around in the Superman universe as well.

Comment: ...Did you delete it once it was a comment?  I don't see any comments on that question.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the comment.

Comment: You might find this interesting as a general reference/starting point for answers vs comments: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer

Answer (score 5):

One of the oddities about this site is a lot of the questions we tackle have no really good answer. However, we do our best to take each question as seriously as possible. Ex. [my question on Gremlins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11225/3958). Honestly, your answer could have been acceptable if you had a well founded argument why it would be the Nexus, and came with a tone of seriousness not sarcasm.

Remember SE is a site for professionals, so we examine things in the SciFi world first with an eye towards a realistic, rational answer (or at least in-universe/cannon answer).

The idea that it may be the nexus is as good as any other that I can think of, I would say its how you presented your argument that made it seem more appropriate as a comment.

I would advise you to always consider how plausible it is that someone ACCEPTS your answer, as you consider whether it should be an answer.

I would say its the Space Core from Portal myself, but I would say that in chat :D

Comment: Fascinating.  I didn't intend sarcasm, but that apparently is how the answer was read by some.

Comment: the words "clearly" sets the tone for it I think.

Comment: Also if you backed it up with side by side images that show that it looks similar, you would have won many a points I think

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1597/how-do-we-handle-answers-that-dont-answer-the-question) and associated answers is relevant.

I noticed your answer yesterday, and I believe I commented and downvoted.  I did not flag, as I felt you were actually addressing the question.  As Pyrodante mentioned, you presented no supporting evidence, and therefore your answer was of poor quality.  But it was still, imo, an answer.

It could be argued that it fits item #3 of Pearsonartphoto's [answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1603/1359), but the fact that you included the second sentence could also be seen as evidence that you took it beyond a "short one-liner that while funny, isn't intended as a serious answer".  Still, I can see it being a judgement call on the part of the moderator who converted it, and if there were one or more flags on the answer, then it probably wasn't a bad call.