# Why were the "Not an Answer" flags on this post about wandless magic in Harry Potter declined?

Tags: support, flagging, specific-answer, not-an-answer

[Are there any spells that a wizard/witch can cast without a wand in the Harry Potter universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2622/19561)

This question was ["answered"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/163184/19561) by a post going off on a tangent about soldiers being able to fight without a sword. That post does in no way address the question asked *if* there are any spells that can be cast wandless and if so, how wandless magic works. It does not give "an in-universe explanation" (words *and emphasis* by the OP).

**It fails to address the question.**

Yet *at least* three separate "Not an Answer" flags (by users Gallifreyan, Mithrandir, and yours truly) were rejected.

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer
>
> [image: A screenshot showing the rejected flag of user Mithrandir]

This post is *not even wrong*; it does not address the question and goes off on a tangent. It does not answer the questions, neither the one asked in the title, nor the ones in the body.

**So why were these "Not an Answer" flags declined?**

Comment: don't we have this discussion every time someone's NAA Flag is declined? The flag doesn't mean what you think it means. You think it means "this is not an answer to the question" -- not surprising, since that's what it says -- but that's not what it means. It means "this post isn't an answer to _any_ question."

Comment: @KutuluMike so what question is answered by that post?

Comment: "do you think wizards can cast magic without wands?"

Comment: OP is asking what, if any, spells can be cast without a wand. "Answer" says wizards "should" e able to do something without their wands as well. No mention of actual spells.

Comment: What OP is asking is irrelevant. You can tell if the NAA flag applies or not just by reading the answer. If you have to check the question to see if NAA applies, then it doesn't.

Comment: Again from the SE FAQ: "Do not use this flag when: ... You have to consider the question, other answers, or even the comments on the answer itself in order to determine if an answer is not-an-answer"

Comment: @KutuluMike You're wrong. I check what the question asks, then I check the answer. If the answer doesn't address the question it was posted under, I don't check if it is an answer to some other question, I downvote and flag.

Comment: _I_ am not wrong, _Stack Exchange_ is wrong, since I'm just quoting what their FAQ says.

Answer (score 5):

Because "NAA" doesn't mean what any reasonable person thinks it means. Most people assume "Not An Answer" means that the post does not answer the question being asked. It **doesn't**. It means "the thing that was posted is in no way, shape, or form an answer to **any** question".

The things that [qualify for not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag) include:

- An answer that's actually a different question.
- An answer that's asking for clarification.
- An answer that's just a "thanks" or "me, too"
- An answer that's a comment or message to the OP or other users.

If the thing that's in the post is written in the form of an answer to a question, then the NAA flag isn't appropriate. In this case, the OP's answer is rambling, largely off-topic, and entirely conjecture, but they *are* in a very odd sense trying to say that yes, wizards can cast magic without wands. So, it's an answer.

Comment: Just to clarify: this isn't my personal opinion. This is the stated criteria that Stack Exchange wants mods to use to handle those flags. Downvoting me ain't gonna change that.

Comment: The flag reason states: "This was posted as an answer, **but it does not attempt to answer the question.** It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether. " Not *any* question - *the* question.

Comment: @KutuluMike I know. And I don't blame you for quoting the SE policy.

Comment: Also see (and vote for): https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11087/19561

Comment: So what is the correct flag if there is one? Cause I know when those answers hit the Very Low Quality Posts review queue they get swept away very quickly, so it seems equally the case that they aren't wanted on the site

Comment: Presumably 'very low quality' but I'm sure I've read discussions along the lines of, it's regrettable that a very low quality flag exists because it's essentially meaningless

Comment: If this is true it's a complete change from how flagging has been used since as long as I can remember.

Comment: that is kind of my point. _no one_ does it right, and so people are always frustrated when a moderator "follows the rules".

Comment: This answer isn't entirely wrong, but glosses over the usual point of contention: that last bullet. Divining how (or if) a specific response is intended to solve a problem is prone to both errors and good ol' differences of opinion; that's why there are multiple moderators, multiple reviewers, multiple voters etc. Pretty much everyone agrees that "Buy ZapIT pills!" isn't an answer to most questions, but I'd guess a much smaller number of people know that some rant about the nature of magic and/or soldiering isn't an answer to that specific question. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286366

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Disclaimer: I declined two of the NaA flags on this post, and another mod declined the third.</sup>

The question includes the following:

> What is the explanation for why some spells can be cast without a wand and is there an **in-universe** explanation for why this isn't done?

Akhil's answer attempts to address this by making an [argument from analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_analogy) using soldiers:

> In my opinion we should consider an example of a Soldier. a soldier use a weapon to fight, but he can also fight without any weapon by using only his arms. Still he is much more deadly and harmful with a weapon compared to the empty handed. [...]
>
> Same things happens with a wizard as he is trained in magic but more powerful with a wand, and a muggle can not do magic.

This is surely at least an attempt to answer the question, even if a poor one (I don't even think it's *that* poor an attempt, but in any case that's not what NaA flags are for). The answerer is explaining why wizards tend to use wands even though they can do magic without them, by drawing a comparison with soldiers who use weapons despite being trained in unarmed combat.

---

In any case, thanks to the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/278659), the answer **has since been deleted** by three high-rep users.